# AWS Signature Version 4 is giving invalid signature value for 30th December 2019

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are preparing presigned URL for AWS files. We are using AWS Signature Version 4. Since today morning, December 30th, 2019, it is throwing Signature doesn't match error. If prepare the URL using date 28th December, URL works fine. What is the reason for this? This happened last year as well. Last year issue fixed automatically on 1st of January.

Comment: Works fine for me. I generated a pre-signed URL that expires in 3600 seconds (`X-Amz-Date=20191230T140809Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600`). I then downloaded the underlying file using the pre-signed URL with no problems. Can you provide more details of what you are doing here?

Comment: @jarmod i am simply preparing presigned URL using Amazon File Key, AWS Access Key Id and AWS Secret Key. Expiry duration is 6 days for me. I tried with 3600 seconds as well. But no luck.

Comment: How are you generating the pre-signed URL? Also, try using the awscli, for example `aws s3 presign s3://mybucket/mycat.png` and then visit the resulting URL.

Comment: check your machine/server date time. some times if it goes back or ahead, these issues comes.

Comment: @AshishModi that isn't correct.  Inaccurate date/time can cause errors but it will not cause the specific error mentioned, here, *signature does not match*.

Comment: Wild guess based on your mentioning of 30th December: Are you generating the URLs from Java using `SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");`? https://www.juandebravo.com/2015/04/10/java-yyyy-date-format/